# Creating CRUD interface for Ruby-on-Rails App that uses an Array-type via terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am creating a Ruby on Rails Application where I want to create a CRUD interface that will allow me to store records in a postgresql database. Eventually this will become part of the backend for an iOS game I am developing. I want to store arrays in these records of text and/or integer types respectively, but I don't know how...

So far I can create a CRUD interface via terminal, for example using a 'POST' model with the scaffold command like..

```
$ bin/rails generate scaffold post first_name:text last_name:text date_of_birth:date
```

This will produce a database migration file that looks like

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :first_name
      t.text :last_name
      t.date :date_of_birth

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

To best illustrate what I want to achieve, I have created the following example desired database migration file.

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :player do |t|
      t.text :player_name, null: false
      t.text :player_email, null: false
      t.integer :tokens_collected_by_level, array: true, default: []
      t.text :items_collected, array: true, default: []
    end
  end
end
```

In order to help me understand how to create a CRUD interface for a Ruby on Rails App USING arrays, via Terminal.. What would be the corresponding 'bin/rails generate scaffold post ... ' command to execute, to generate the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [accepted column modifiers accepted](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers) for Rails edge (> 4.2), that can [be passed using curly braces](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#passing-modifiers):

> **limit** Sets the maximum size of the string/text/binary/integer fields.
>
> **precision** Defines the precision for the decimal fields, representing
> the total number of digits in the number.
>
> **scale** Defines the scale for the decimal fields, representing the number of digits after the decimal point.
>
> **polymorphic** Adds a type column for belongs_to
> associations.
>
> **null** Allows or disallows NULL values in the column.
>
> **default** Allows to set a default value on the column. Note that if you
> are using a dynamic value (such as a date), the default will only be
> calculated the first time (i.e. on the date the migration is applied).
>
> **index** Adds an index for the column.
>
> **required** Adds required: true for belongs_to associations and null: false to the column in the migration.

`array: true` is not a valid option for a field type in Rails. You can use [`serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) to store your array in a `:text` field and handle the default there.

So in your example:

```
bin/rails generate model Post player_name:text:required player_email:text:required tokens_collected_by_level:text items_collected:text
```

Comment: Ahhh ofc, so I would store my arrays as text and convert them as needed. So simple.. you sir have been most helpful!